# Completely open sourced ARM board

Tags: linux-kernel

I am learning to customize the Linux kernel to make it portable on embedded systems. To test my customized kernel , i want a completely open sourced ARM board. I investigated the Raspberry pi but some it's firmware (i.e. "start.elf") is not open source. Can anybody name an ARM board which is completely open source?

Also are there any such board whose ROM/AVRAM contents can also be replaced?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "completely open source" you mean open source bootloader, kernel and OS (correct me if I'm wrong), then I would recommend one of [Beagle](http://beagleboard.org/Products/) family boards -- they are inexpensive, user friendly and have a good community support. Their open source stack consists of *U-Boot*, *Linux kernel* and one of few available distributions. If you need advanced features, check out [EVM's by Texas Instrument](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/tools-software/designkits.page), but they cost *much* more.

Comment: thank so much! I checked Beagle boards , it's according to my need

Answer (score 1):

Jetson-TK1 from nvidia, is a developer platform, 
does have u-boot loader, Linux Kernel and rootfs,
The board layout is also shared, you can recompile things for you.
It comes with 2GB RAM, a 2.3GHz Quad core processor, with GPU that is ready for CUDA kind of high level programming

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813190005